# Only one usage of each socket address error no 2002 showing on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, server, wamp

My website deployed on windows XP using WAMP. I see this error from last many days every thing were working fine. I don't know where is the problem. some buddy help

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] Only
>   one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted.
>       (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\wamp\www\ESP\ESP.php on line 7

where is the problem? my code or server side issue?

on line 7 this code is located

```
$con = mysql_connect($localhost,$root,$rootpass);//this is the line number 7
and it is unchanged from last many days. so why error now is showing?
```

and

```
$localhost = "localhost";
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx

Comment: can you find httdp.conf ?

Comment: @Drew, I have the same error, how do I fix it using httpd.conf?

Comment: @Atara well i dont remember exactly! i guess i were requesting to server too much that why this error occur. check how many request u r doing on server

Comment: is that literally your error message or something different @Atara

Comment: Here was a followup from Mohammad [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1012103/Only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-error-Deplye)

Comment: @Drew, wamp on xp, I receive -
DB Connect SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.